# Question about the diffraction of electrons

Tags: electrons, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

[image]
This question concerns the diagram on the left.

[image]

This is the set up.

My question is that, why is collector current not an increasing function of the KE of the electrons? I can understand the graph on the right as at some angles the electrons constructively interfere and at others they destructively interfere, so there will be maxima and minima. But why is this so for the graph on the left? Here we are fixing the angle and just varying the potential difference.

Comment: And what does varying the electron energy do?

Comment: I thought it would change the current in the detector.

Comment: What property of interest for diffraction changes with energy?

Comment: Is it that as the electrons energy increases, its de broglie wavelength decreases so it diffracts through a larger angle, meaning less of the electrons actually reach the detector?